# Radio buttons are not clickable

Tags: php, html

When executed, the radio buttons are not working, which they were when they were introduced without PHP.
Here is my code:

```
    <td><?php echo date('l');?></td>

    <?php 
    while ($meal_num<=4)
    {
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row[$meal_num+2];
    echo '<form action="rating.php?hostel='.$hostel.'&meal_type='.$meal_num.'" method="POST"><br><br>';
    ?>
    <span class="radiolabel" >
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-1" value="1" />
        <label for="radio-1">1</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-2" value="2"/>
        <label for="radio-2">2</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-3" value="3"/>
        <label for="radio-3">3</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-4" value="4"/>
        <label for="radio-4">4</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-5" value="5"/>
        <label for="radio-5">5</label>
    </span>&nbsp;
    <span> <input type="submit" class="submitbutton1" value="OK"></span>
</form>
    </td>
    <?php 
    $meal_num=$meal_num+1;
    }?>
  </tr>  
 </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not clickable"? and how are you using it after?

Comment: Post your complete code and Explain your Question in some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your radio inputs are in a while loop, so you recreate multiple sets of radio inputs with the same set of ids.

Try attributing a different value for "id" for each loop that's executed with an increment number.

For example:

```
$i = 1;

while (blabla) {
    echo '<input type="radio" id="radio-'.$i.'" name="radio1" />';
    $i++;
}
```

So the radios from one loop will not interfere with the radios from another loop.
After each radio you put, you increment the number so the id will never be the same (an id should be unique in a page).